# Question about Riemann Mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

The Riemann mapping theorem says that given a simply connected region R not all off $\mathbb{C}$ and $z_0 \in R$ then there is a unique conformal map $f: R \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z_0) = 0$ and $f'(z_0) > 0$.  What I am unclear about is what exactly the uniqueness statement means?  Is the value $f'(z_0)$ unique?  That is, given $z_0$, is $|f'(z_0)|$ unique?  As in, there do not exist different conformal maps $f:R \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ with $f(z_0) = 0$ and $|f'(z_0)| = 0.5$ for one map, and $0.24$ say for another?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think the idea is that if you have one map $f:R\rightarrow\mathbb C$ with $f(z_0)=0$, then every other map $z\mapsto e^{i\theta}f(z)$ has the same property. The requirement that $f'(z_0)>0$  picks one of these.

Comment: It means that if $f,g$ are any two mappings with $f(z_0)=g(z_0)=0$ and positive real $f'(z_0)$ and $g'(z_0)$ (a priori completely unrelated), then $f=g$ everywhere (so $f'=g'$ as well, etc.). As a side note, it would be nice to have some language ministry (or whatever it is called in your part of the world) to establish some canonical way of spelling "Riemann" for its constituents so that the poor outsiders would not have to guess if Reimann and Remiann is the same person or not ;)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, $f'(z_0)$ is unique.  And the man's name is neither "Reimann" (as in your title) nor "remiann" (as in the first sentence of your question) but "Riemann".

Answer (score 2):

Existence is the main contents of the Riemann mapping theorem. Uniqueness is a simple consequence of the classification of holomorphic automorphisms of the unit disk, given by the Schwarz lemma.